# Published property in data factory dataset json

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have noticed that upon saving dataset definition in data factory via the azure portal that

> "published": false

Appears in the definition, I have seen dataset's work fine with published false. But also seen some seemingly only start working with published: true, however that might of been a coincidence.

I've been unable to find any documentation for this property.

```
{
    "name": "DataLakeDummyXmlInput",
    "properties": {
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
```

Comment: Great thanks, @wBob if you post as an answer I'll mark it so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property is currently classified as "legacy" as described by a Microsoft employee [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6da7744-1209-423a-9134-bec0c1b9a8de/azure-data-factory-published-false-what-does-this-element-mean?forum=AzureDataFactory):

> ...this is a legacy element in our object model.

The link also mentions the possibility of "lighting it up as a future feature" which translates as it may come in to use in the future.  For now, don't worry about it.